# How to update dependent dropdown while fetching values from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo, dropdown

I am unable to retrieve values into Dependent dropdown from database...I have 3 tables for "division" ,"sub-depot","depot" respectively.Main table is "bus" .I am unable to convert the values into their respective id while retriving .
I am using Php PDO .
Could any one please help me with jquery and php part to retrive values in dropdown and then again update it .
My code is as follows:

view_bus_details.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql="select div_id,div_name from division";
$stmt=$connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrCountry=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
    <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" align="left">Add Bus Details</h4>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <label>Enter Bus Name *</label>
         <input type="text" name="b_num" id="b_num" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg. MH30 AB 1234" required>
         <br />
         <label>Select Division Name *</label>
         <select class="form-control select2bs4" id="country" name="div1">
                              <option value="-1">Select Division</option>
                                <?php
                                 foreach($arrCountry as $country){
                                ?>
                                   <option value="<?php echo $country['div_id']?>">
                                    <?php echo $country['div_name'] ?>
                                      
                                    </option>
                                <?php
                                 }
                                ?>
                </select>
         <br />

         <label>Select Sub-Depot Name *</label>
                <select class="form-control select2bs4" id="state" name="div2">
                          <option value="">Select Sub-Depot</option>
                      </select>
         <br />
         <label>Select  Depot Name *</label>
                 <select class="form-control select2bs4" id="city" name="div3">
                            <option value="">Select Depot</option>
                      </select>
         <br />
              <label>Select Bus Type *</label>
              <select class="form-control select2bs4" id="bus_type" name="bus_type" required="required">
                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Select Bus Type</option>
                    <option value="Ordinary">Ordinary</option>
                    <option value="Yashwanti">Yashwanti</option>
                    <option value="Hirakani">Hirakani</option>
                    <option value="Asiad">Asiad</option>
                    <option value="Pariwartan">Pariwartan</option>
                    <option value="Sheetal">Sheetal</option>
                    <option value="Shivneri(AC)">Shivneri(AC)</option>
                    <option value="Shivneri(AC) Sleeper">Shivneri(AC) Sleeper</option>
                    <option value="Ashwamedh">Ashwamedh</option>
                    <option value="Shivshahi(AC)">Shivshahi(AC)</option>
                    <option value="Shivshahi(AC) Sleeper">Shivshahi(AC) Sleeper</option>
                    <option value="City Bus">City Bus</option>
                    <option value="Parcel">Parcel</option>
                    <option value="Tourism">Tourism</option>
                    <option value="Yatra">Yatra</option>
              </select>
              <br />
         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
         <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
         <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
       </div>
          <div id="divLoading"></div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
     
     var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
      "processing":true,
      "serverSide":true,
      "order":[],
      "ajax":{
       url:"fetch.php",
       type:"POST"
      },
      "columnDefs":[
       {
        "targets":[5,6],
        "orderable":false,
       },
      ],

     });

     $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var bnum = $('#b_num').val();
      var d1 = $('#div1').val();
      var d2 = $('#div2').val();
      var d3 = $('#div3').val();
      var btype = $('#bus_type').val();
      


      if(bnum != '' && d1 != '' && d2 != '' && d3 != '' && btype != '')
      {
       $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        method:'POST',
        data:new FormData(this),
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data)
        {
         alert(data);
         $('#user_form')[0].reset();
         $('#userModal').modal('hide');
         dataTable.ajax.reload();
        }
       });
      }
      else
      {
       alert("All Fields Are Required");
      }
     });
     
     $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
      var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch_single.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{user_id:user_id},
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('#userModal').modal('show');
        $('#b_num').val(data.b_num);





        $('#div1').val(data.div_name);
        $('#div2').val(data.sub_depot);
        $('#div3').val(data.depot_name);
        $('#bus_type').val(data.b_type);
        // $('.modal-title').text("Edit Route");
        $('#user_id').val(user_id);
        $('#action').val("Update");
        $('#operation').val("Edit");
       }
      })
     });
     
     $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
      var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Bus Record?"))
      {
       $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{user_id:user_id},
        success:function(data)
        {
         alert(data);
         dataTable.ajax.reload();
        }
       });
      }
      else
      {
       return false; 
      }
     });
     
     
    });
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#country').change(function(){
          var id=jQuery(this).val();
          if(id=='-1'){
            jQuery('#state').html('<option value="-1">Select Sub_depot</option>');
          }else{
            $("#divLoading").addClass('show');
            jQuery('#state').html('<option value="-1">Select Sub_depot</option>');
            jQuery('#city').html('<option value="-1">Select Depot</option>');
            jQuery.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'get_data.php',
              data:'id='+id+'&type=state',
              success:function(result){
                $("#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                jQuery('#state').append(result);
              }
            });
          }
        });
        jQuery('#state').change(function(){
          var id=jQuery(this).val();
          if(id=='-1'){
            jQuery('#city').html('<option value="-1">Select Depot</option>');
          }else{
            $("#divLoading").addClass('show');
            jQuery('#city').html('<option value="-1">Select Depot</option>');
            jQuery.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'get_depot.php',
              data:'id='+id+'&type=city',
              success:function(result){
                $("#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                jQuery('#city').append(result);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
      </script>
```

fetch_single.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
 $output = array();
 $statement = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM bus 
  WHERE b_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' 
  LIMIT 1"
 );
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output["b_num"] = $row["b_num"];
  $output["div_name"] = $row["div_name"];
  $output["sub_depot"] = $row["sub_depot"];
  $output["depot_name"] = $row["depot_name"];
  $output["b_type"] = $row["b_type"];
 
 }
 echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

get_data.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$type=$_POST['type'];

if($type=='city'){
 $sql="select depot_id,depot_name from depot where sub_depot_id='$id'";
}else{
 $sql="select sub_depot_id,sub_depot_name from sub_depot where div_id='$id'";
}
$stmt=$connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arr=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$html='';
foreach($arr as $list){
 $html.='<option value='.$list['sub_depot_id'].'>'.$list['sub_depot_name'].'</option>';
}
echo $html;
?>
```

get_depot.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$type=$_POST['type'];

if($type=='city'){
 $sql="SELECT depot_id,depot_name from depot where sub_depot_id='$id'";
}
else
{
 $sql="SELECT sub_depot_id,sub_depot_name from sub_depot where div_id='$id'";
}
$stmt=$connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arr=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$html='';
foreach($arr as $list){
 $html.='<option value='.$list['depot_id'].'>'.$list['depot_name'].'</option>';
}
echo $html;
?>
```

insert.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');

if(isset($_POST["operation"]))
{
 if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
 {
// try{
 $output1 = array();
 $statement1 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT div_name FROM division 
  WHERE div_id = '".$_POST["div1"]."' " );
 $statement1->execute();
 $result1 = $statement1->fetch();
 $f1 = $result1['div_name'] ;
 // echo $f1;
// }
// catch(Exception $ex){
//  echo( $ex => getMessage());
// }
// try{
 $output2 = array();
 $statement2 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT sub_depot_name FROM sub_depot 
  WHERE sub_depot_id = '".$_POST["div2"]."' " );
 $statement2->execute();
 $result2 = $statement2->fetch();
 $f2 = $result2['sub_depot_name'];
// }
// catch(Exception $ex1){
//  echo( $ex1 => getMessage());
// } // echo $f2;
// try{
 $output3 = array();
 $statement3 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT depot_name FROM depot 
  WHERE depot_id = '".$_POST["div3"]."' " );
 $statement3->execute();
 $result3 = $statement3->fetch();
 $f3 = $result3['depot_name'];
 // echo $f3;
// }
// catch(Exception $ex2){
//  echo( $ex2 => getMessage());
// }
  
 $statement = $connection->prepare("
   INSERT INTO bus (b_num, div_name, sub_depot, depot_name, b_type) 
   VALUES (:b_num, :div_name, :sub_depot, :depot_name, :b_type) ");


  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':b_num'     => $_POST["b_num"],
    ':div_name'  => $f1,
    ':sub_depot' => $f2,
    ':depot_name' => $f3,
    ':b_type'     => $_POST["bus_type"]
   )
  );
  if(!empty($result))
  {
   echo 'Data Inserted';
  }
  else{
   echo "Opps!!!There was an error while Inserting Data!";
  }
 }
 if($_POST["operation"] == "Edit")
 {
// try{
 $output4 = array();
 $statement4 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT div_name FROM division 
  WHERE div_id = '".$_POST["div1"]."' " );
 $statement4->execute();
 $result4 = $statement4->fetch();
 $f4 = $result4['div_name'] ;
 // echo $f1;
// }
// catch(Exception $ex3){
//  echo( $ex3 => getMessage());
// }
// try{
 $output5 = array();
 $statement5 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT sub_depot_name FROM sub_depot 
  WHERE sub_depot_id = '".$_POST["div2"]."' " );
 $statement5->execute();
 $result5 = $statement5->fetch();
 $f5 = $result5['sub_depot_name'];
 // echo $f2;
// }
// catch(Exception $ex4){
//  echo( $ex4 => getMessage());
// }
// try{
 $output6 = array();
 $statement6 = $connection->prepare(
  "SELECT depot_name FROM depot 
  WHERE depot_id = '".$_POST["div3"]."' " );
 $statement6->execute();
 $result6 = $statement6->fetch();
 $f6 = $result6['depot_name'];
// }
// catch(Exception $ex5){
//  echo( $ex5 => getMessage());
// }
  $statement = $connection->prepare(
   " UPDATE bus 
     SET b_num = :b_num, div_name = :div_name, sub_depot = :sub_depot, depot_name = :depot_name, 
    b_type =  :b_type
     WHERE b_id = :b_id " );
  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':b_num'     => $_POST["b_num"],
    ':div_name'  => $f4,
    ':sub_depot' => $f5,
    ':depot_name' => $f6,
    ':b_type'     => $_POST["bus_type"]
   )
  );
  if(!empty($result))
  {
   echo 'Data Updated';
  }
  else{
   echo "Opps!!!There was an error while Updating Data!";
  }
 }
}

?>
```

My Database....
1)bus : `b_id`, `b_num`, `div_name`, `sub_depot`, `depot_name`, `b_type`
2)division:  `div_id`, `div_name`
3)sub_depot: `sub_depot_id`, `sub_depot_name`, `div_id`
4)depot: `depot_id`, `depot_name`, `sub_depot_id`

Please help as I don't have much knowledge...

Comment: Beware, you code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements

Comment: Yes sir....everywhere I have used prepare statements....please tell where missing..

Comment: You should not insert data coming from `$_POST` directly in the sql but use parameters. An example is at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp